# converting vinyls to electronic music on my linux computer

Tags: music

I have some old vinyls which I would like to convert to something I can play on my computer. I just bought a record player which comes with a USB.. I have unsuccessfully searched through all the Software available to me via my linux system. Is there such a thing?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is the record player recognized as an audio input device (e.g. in `pavucontrol`)? It's unclear if you need a driver (when the device is not recognized) or you're looking for a general-purpose audio recording software (e.g. Audacity).

Comment: It would be useful to mention the exact model of record player. The USB must be there for a reason and it would be surprising that no user notice is available.

Comment: if it s pure-audio output on usb juste use a fifo node & use it as a pipe and aucat to any media file encoder  ` anyencoter <fifopipe options > mediafile.mp4 &`  and `aucat device > fifopipe`    you can also do the same from a specialized application with GUI

Comment: thank you. Audacity was a great answer. To the others who answered, I am not at that level of understanding. Thanks though